# Why don't I see all the grid lines in my combined contour plots?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to display four continuous functions, but when I try to combine them withe a single `Show`, I can't see the second vertical line. I suppose the problem is with the `GridLines`.

The code is:

```
j = -1;
a2 = 3.968342707518218;
a1 = 3.275794729726671;
NalfaF = -0.749964;
alfaF1 = 0.749964;
mu = 10^-3;
Ntot = NalfaF*mu;
tot1 = alfaF1*mu;
alfaF2 = 1.54553;
tot2 = alfaF2*mu;
k = 
 Show[ContourPlot[(Sqrt[(16 tot1 y)/3 (1 + tot1/(27 y^3))] - (
       2 tot1)/(9 j y)) (x - 0.95 a1) == 0.002, {x, -10, 10}, {y, 
    0, .3}, PlotRange -> {{2.50, 4.5}, {0., 0.3}}, 
   ContourShading -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[8], Text["2:1", {a1 + 0.1, 0.01}], 
     Black, Point[{a1, 0.}]}, GridLines -> {{a1}, {}}],
  ContourPlot[(-Sqrt[(16 tot1*y)/3 (1 + tot1/(27 y^3))] - (2 tot1)/(
       9 j y)) (x - 1.17 a1) == 0.004, {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, .3}, 
   PlotRange -> {{2.50, 4.5}, {0., 0.3}}, ContourShading -> None, 
   GridLines -> {{a1}, {}}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[8], Text["2:1", {a1 + 0.1, 0.01}], 
     Black, Point[{a1, 0.}]}], 
  ContourPlot[(Sqrt[(16 tot2 y)/3 (1 + tot2/(27 y^3))] - (2 tot2)/(
       9 j y)) (x - 0.95 a2) == 0.002, {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, .3}, 
   PlotRange -> {{2.50, 4.5}, {0., 0.3}}, ContourShading -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, 
   Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[8], Text["3:2", {a2 + 0.1, 0.01}], 
     Black, Point[{a2, 0.}]}, GridLines -> {{a2}, {}}],
  ContourPlot[(-Sqrt[(16 tot2*y)/3 (1 + tot2/(27 y^3))] - (2 tot2)/(
       9 j y)) (x - 1.1 a2) == 0.004, {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, .3}, 
   PlotRange -> {{2.50, 4.5}, {0., 0.3}}, ContourShading -> None, 
   GridLines -> {{a2}, {}}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[8], Text["3:2", {a2 + 0.1, 0.01}], 
     Black, Point[{a2, 0.}]}]]
```

How can I make sure both vertical lines show?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not `GridLines` itself. The issue is that when you have different values for the same options across multiple plots in a `Show`, the option values specified in the first plot prevail.

Merging the `GridLines` and `Epilog` option values into the first plot will vastly simplify your code:

```
k = Show[ContourPlot[(Sqrt[(16 tot1 y)/
          3 (1 + tot1/(27 y^3))] - (2 tot1)/(9 j y)) (x - 0.95 a1) == 
    0.002, {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, .3}, 
   PlotRange -> {{2.50, 4.5}, {0., 0.3}}, ContourShading -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, 
   Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[8], Text["2:1", {a1 + 0.1, 0.01}], 
     Text["3:2", {a2 + 0.1, 0.01}], Black, Point[{a2, 0.}], 
     Point[{a1, 0.}]}, GridLines -> {{a1, a2}, {}}], 
  ContourPlot[(-Sqrt[(16 tot1*y)/
           3 (1 + tot1/(27 y^3))] - (2 tot1)/(9 j y)) (x - 1.17 a1) ==
     0.004, {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, .3}, ContourShading -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 100], 
  ContourPlot[(Sqrt[(16 tot2 y)/
          3 (1 + tot2/(27 y^3))] - (2 tot2)/(9 j y)) (x - 0.95 a2) == 
    0.002, {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, .3}, ContourShading -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 100], 
  ContourPlot[(-Sqrt[(16 tot2*y)/
           3 (1 + tot2/(27 y^3))] - (2 tot2)/(9 j y)) (x - 1.1 a2) == 
    0.004, {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, .3}, ContourShading -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 100]]
```

[image]

Here is a simpler example to make it clear what is going on:

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Green], 
 Plot[Cos[2 x], {x, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]]
```

[image]

As you can see, `PlotStyle` doesn't propagate to both plots, because it is a characteristic of the line, while `PlotRange` does, because it is a characteristic of the plot, if that makes sense.

Comment: FYI I'm getting `Power::infy` errors from this code (combined with the OP's) but I'm too lazy to check why.